# On Click of Floating Action Button the Icon has to be changed

Tags: android

When clicking the Floating Action button in Android, how can I change the icon image from "Play" to "Pause"?

[image: Android screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Changing FloatingActionButton source:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_full_sad, context.getTheme()));
        } else {
            floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_full_sad));
    }
```

Hope to help!

Comment: Don't  you think it should Image Resource aka src instead of drawable.

Comment: yea you are right to , in your case must be work too , but i think that in my case should work ? are you not agree?

Comment: Drawable are used for backgrounds and image resource is used for icon. Using drawable will work but not good practise.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I tried this. if(counter == 0){
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp);
                }
                if(counter == 1){
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp);
                    counter = -1;
                }
                counter++;

Answer (score 0):

Those resources as many others are available on the [google design website](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#getting-icons) and should be put on your res drawable folder.

Then as mentioned by Kristiyan Varbanov and Keshav setImageResource is best practice

```
fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_dark);
fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_dark);
```